# Is there an established way to write conditional probability for whole expression?

Tags: conditional-probability, notation

I am writing a methodological paper and I have expression like this, which is slightly more complicated bayes rule, because everything is conditioned by `c`:

[image]

Is there some established math notation that would say that the whole expression on the right side is conditioned by c? So that I don't have to write it everywhere and can simplify the expression to something close to

[image]

PS: journals guidelines won't help, no journal has guidelines this detailed :)
with maybe adding a huge